# Simplify $\ln(2) (2^{x+1} - 2^{4-x}) = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The equation in the title is a part of my assignment and I was wondering why the $\ln(2)$ is left out when solving the whole equation? Why is $\ln(2)$ irrelevant and can you just continue with $2^{x+1} - 2^{4-x} = 0$?

Another example: $2(x+3) = 0$. Why is the "$2$" irrelevant here and can we use what's between the brackets "$(x+3)$" to solve the equation? I mean obviously $2(x+3)$ could be written out as $2x + 6$ and then be solved like that as well, but why is $(x+3) = 0$ enough?

I hope you can answer my question.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Because your first step can be to divide both sides by $\ln(2)$.

Comment: $$\ln(2) (2^{x+1} - 2^{4-x}) = 0 \\or\\\ln(2)\times (2^{x+1} - 2^{4-x}) = 0$$ ?

Comment: $ab=0$ implies $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Comment: Note that "$2(x-1)=0$ if and only if $x-1=0$" is **true**, however, "$x(x-1)=0$ if and only if $x-1$" is **not true**.

Comment: Surb, I'm guessing you mean, after "however", $x(x-1)= 0 \iff x-1= 0$ is **not true** because in the first case one factor is a constant $\neq 0$, but in the second case, each factor is a function of $x$, so that, what **IS true* wrt the second example is that $x(x-1) = 0 \iff (x=0$ or $x-1 = 0)$.

Comment: I got carried away, I just meant to finish the $\iff x-1 = 0$ which is indeed false.

Comment: David:  Of course, we can go your route, and note that $$2(x+3) = 0\iff 2x + 6 = 0 \iff 2x = -6 \iff x = \frac {-6}{2} = -3$$ Canceling the factor $2\neq 0$ allows us to jump right to $x+3= 0 \iff x=-3$.  You don't ***have to*** simplify at the start, but you're going to have to simplify at some point, to solve for x.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\ln(2) \ne 0$ so we can divide by it.  Then

$$\require{cancel}\ln(2) (2^{x+1} - 2^{4-x}) = 0
\iff \color{red}{\frac{\color{black}{\color{blue}{\cancel{\color{black}{\ln(2)}}} (2^{x+1} - 2^{4-x})}}{\color{blue}{\cancel{\color{red}{\ln(2)}}}}} = \color{red}{\frac{\color{black}{0}}{\ln(2)}}
\iff 2^{x+1} - 2^{4-x} = 0$$

Exactly the same thing allows us to simplify $2(x+3)=0$ to the equation $x+3=0$.  First we notice that $2\ne 0$.  And thus we can divide by it:

$$\require{cancel}2 (x+3) = 0
\iff \color{red}{\frac{\color{black}{\color{blue}{\cancel{\color{black}{2}}} (x+3)}}{\color{blue}{\cancel{\color{red}{2}}}}} = \color{red}{\frac{\color{black}{0}}{2}}
\iff x+3 = 0$$

Comment: I upvoted this, as "just right" (showing the division by $\ln 2$ after noting $\ln 2\neq 0$ without going on to solve it line by line.)

Comment: Now I wish I could upvote again!

Answer (score 1):

Consider $ 2(x+3) = 0$. You are trying to find which are the values of $x$ for which $2(x+3)$ is zero. Since it is a multiplication of $2$ and $x+3$, the whole term is zero when at least one of the two terms is zero (since $0$ times something is $0$). The first one (i.e., $2$) is a number different from zero, hence it suffices to find the values of $x$ for which $x+3 = 0$.

The same reasoning applies to $\ln(2) (2^{(x+1)} - 2^{(4-x)}) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

When you have something like in your example:

$$
2(x+3) = 0
$$

you are essentially multiplying two numbers to get zero. This can only happen if at least one of the two factors (in this case there is only two factors) is zero. Obviously, the first factor, the integer 2 is not zero. The only choice is the other factor $$(x+3)$$ has to be zero. That's why this factor is enough for you to solve the equation. The same logic can be applied to any other equation of a similar form.

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln { 2 } \left( { 2 }^{ x+1 }-{ 2 }^{ 4-x } \right) =0\\ { 2 }^{ x+1 }={ 2 }^{ 4-x }\\ x+1=4-x\\ 2x=3\\ x=1.5$$